# Android TV with sdk 33 is not launching

Tags: android, android-tv

When I create a new project for android tv using android studio. Got this error

```
Error while executing: am start -n "com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.myapplication/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
Failed to launch an application on all devices
```

It's using targetSdk and complieSdk as 33. It's a completely new project using android studio without any single change.
I clean my gladle cache, and invalid cache and restart, the rebuilt the project after cleaning but it's not getting launched.

Comment: What template did you use in Android Studio?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing MainActivity Error when running on Android TV Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75505863/missing-mainactivity-error-when-running-on-android-tv-emulator)

Comment: I think needed to use LAUNCHER instead LEANBACK_LAUNCHER

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have previously implemented a custom splash screen in Android 11 or lower, you’ll need to migrate your app to the SplashScreen API to ensure that it displays correctly in Android 12 and higher.

You can follow the steps here mentioned to fix your app launch issue on API 33: [Click Here for steps](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen/migrate)

**OR**

Might be **launcher category issue**, Pls check AndroidManifest.xml
Here **Leanback launcher** need to add in your main Activity, i assume you have created emulator for google tv, then add both launcher code. it will work.

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.myapplication.MainActivity"    
        android:label="@string/app_name" >    
        <intent-filter>    
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />    
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
        </intent-filter>    
    </activity>
```

Comment: But i did not use or change a single line of code while creating new project using  android studio for android tv. So i did not use any custom splash screen.

Comment: @MeenakshiKhandelwal I have updated answer, pls check and let me know if it works for you or not.

Comment: In my case, adding "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" not works because no android tv devices open this activity instance of the default one.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error.

This settings worked for me:

Use of API `33`

```xml
...
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
...
```

You should check for more details:

https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start

Comment: Using this already   <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> i think in API 33, need to use category.LAUNCHER instead of category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER

Comment: I used to use it that way too, but for API 33, which I started using this way, it worked without any problems.

Comment: So I mentioned it in the comment. You can check the details on the website.